# Android - how to use the same instance of a control on all activities

Tags: android, android-layout, design-patterns, custom-controls

I have a custom user control which is included in all activities and it contains a progress bar control in it. When this control becomes visible in the screen, the progress bar gets updated with the current progress.

I want to make this control a "single instance" type of control so that if the progress bar's progress is updated in a particular screen, it gets reflected in the new screen as well.

I can do this by storing the current progress in, say `SharedPreferences` or a `static` variable and have it checked to display the progress in the new screen.

But I want to know is there a better approach to design & layout such a control or have a type of "Single Instance" (keeping in mind memory leaks) control that can be included in multiple screens?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) to achieve this.

"A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities"

Comment: This seems to be a suitable options.. I didn't think of it as I was under the impression that `Fragments` are mostly used for supporting tablet layouts.. but seems like I can re-use a portion of UI in multiple activities.. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You are right. Fragments can be used on any kind of device, not just tablet. With the support library you can use Fragments on Android devices with version going back to 1.6